# Shell script: if statements evaluated wrong

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I've a simple if statement inside a for loop in a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash


params=(2 3)
for i in "${params[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
    cpus=1
    if [[ $i>20 ]]; then
        echo "wrong! : $i"
        cpus=20
    else
        cpus=$i
    fi
    echo "param-in: $i"
    #do something
done
```

When I execute the code, it evaluates `$i>20` as `TRUE` when `i=3`. Why is that so?

Comment: [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2071) and other common problems

Comment: Just use `((i > 20))` instead of `[[ $i>20 ]]`.

Comment: Though not relevant to your problem, the assignment `cpus=1` seems pointless.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin no, not really

Comment: @onurcanbektas So what is the purpose of `cpus=1` ?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin : It sets `cpus` to 1, but immediately after changes the value again, so you can delete the first assignment. BTW: You tagged your question _bash_ and _zsh_. What's the purpose of the zsh tag? After all, your script is supposed to be a bash script.

Comment: @user1934428 Then `cpus=1` is pointless.

Comment: Exactly! Sorry, my comment was intended to go to the OP, not to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>` performs string comparisons; you want *integer* comparisons. Use `-gt` instead.

Comment: how do you exactly use `-gt`?

Comment: It's an operator, just like `>`. `[[ $i -gt 20 ]]`.

Comment: @onurcanbektas check `help test` or `help [`

Comment: You can also use an arithmetic expression `if (( $i > 20 ))`

Comment: @chepner : Maybe it is worth to add, that even when doing string comparision, bash would reguire a space `[[ $i > 20 ]].